# How do I find details about an installed ODP.NET using the registry?

Tags: registry, odp.net, installscript

I want to find out the following things by searching the registry. I will be checking these things in an [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) project by querying the registry.

1. Is ODP.NET installed on the machine?
2. If yes, what is the version of installed ODP.NET?
3. Is 32-bit or 64-bit ODP.NET installed?

I checked the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ODP.NET` to check the existence of ODP.NET, but I could not get how to find its version and whether it's 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: A man wishes he could help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) driver then look at the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC` key.

Comment: key for 32bit driver HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC

Comment: No, i want one for odp.net, not for odbc.